# Почему останавливается вебсокет?

Tags: python, websocket

```
import amino
import websocket
from time import time as timestamp

client = amino.Client()
client.login(email=<email>, password=<password>)
subclient = amino.SubClient(comId=<comid>, profile=client.profile)

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def run():
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(f"wss://ws1.narvii.com?signbody={client.device_id}%7C{timestamp() * 1000}&sid={client.sid}", on_message=on_message)
    ws.run_forever()
run()
```

Проблема в том, что после 5 минут успешной работы, он почему-то перестает получать сообщения с чатов, при этом программа не вылетает. В чем может быть проблема и как её исправить?

Comment: Перестает принимать данные с существующих подключений? Или на новых также? Если первое, и стоит Nginx, нужно `proxy_read_timeout 86400;`. Если другой веб-сервер, может также стоит подкрутить таймауты. Если на новых - другая причина.

Comment: @TotalPusher судя по собранной мной информации, нужно отправить pong серверу, чтобы он не закрывал соединение. Но как это сделать?

Comment: Веб-сокет - это просто протокол передачи данных. Формат данных вы определяете сами. Думаю вы это знаете. Допустим, у вас есть чат работает в таком упрощенном формате: `{"type": "mesage", "text": "new message"}`. А чтобы сделать пинг-понг, на клиенте раз в минуту отправьте `{"type": "ping"}`, на что сервер должен отвечать `{"type": "pong"}`. Это - просто принцип, как вы сделаете, зависит от вас. Если используется стороняя либа - посмотрите ее доку. Ну а канал закрывает веб-сервер, либо прокся. Чтобы победить Nginx, в нем выставляется таймаут, и пинг-понги не нужны. А против проксей - SSL соед.

Comment: А, это вы делаете клиентскую часть, для стороннего сервера? Тогда смотрите его документацию. В простом случае, можно раз в минуту асинхронно просто опрашивать сервер на предмет какого-нибудь простого действия типа "кто я?". И через пять минут вылетает если ничего нет сообщений? Если сообщения идут стабильно, раз в минуту, и внезапно вырубается, значит другая причина.